# Counting Cells Formula with Criteria: Date & String & Empty Cells

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a whole lot of counting using a table (growing) with over 4,000 entries by date. The table in the picture below is the one I am trying to fill in. I Have a few simple criteria, but I'm not sure how to do this in a formula within a cell that I can copy across this giant table. I've tried multiple CountIf and CountIfs with no luck.

The criteria are as follows: I want to count the number of times a tool occurs (column E) in a particular date (Column A). Only counting when Column W is not empty. Then I want to copy that through this entire table checking every tool by every date.

[image]

The data is coming from this table:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a pivot table be able to do this without any formulas?

Comment: I actually don't have much experience in pivot tables. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: If not using the formula from @ScottCraner , then this may be a perfect reason to start using them / get more knowledge about them. They offer a LOT of cool stuff without using any formulas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COUNTIFS(),  With your date lookups including a time portion we need to bracket the  days.

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$A:$A,">=" & INT($C3),'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"<" & INT($C3)+1,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,D$1,'Sheet1'!$W:$W,"<>")
```

Change Sheet1 to the sheet name in which the data is located.

Put this in D2 and copy over and down the grid.

Comment: So for some reason or another while I thought this was the solution, it's having an issue. if I filter my data by a particular date 7/2, and by one particular tool, there are being listed one more tool than there should be, furthermore it's not omitting the blank spaces for some reason.

Comment: I'm going to spend some time looking at this and let you know if I can find the issue

Comment: I found the referencing was off a touch to the wrong cell from D2. Fixing and i'll let you know

Comment: Okay, so changing the referenced cell worked and now the numbers are all accurate for total lines, but it's not omitting the rows with blank cells. I'll look further into this.

Comment: make sure those cells are truly blank, no spaces or other non printable characters.  @CodingNovice

Comment: Or if the values are returned by formula, that the return is not `" "` which has a space in it.  This is looking for a truly blank cell or a formula that returns `""` without the space. @CodingNovice

Comment: The strangest thing is that the cell showed nothing in it. WHen i clicked to edit it it still showed nothing in it (not even spaces). When I simply hit delete on the cell it finally worked.